# How to have a window closed when a user clicks outside of it using GTK+2?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

I was wondering if there is any simple way for **closing a window when a user clicks out side of it (so it becomes out of focus).**

For example I have this window here:

```c
static void applauncher_create_window(AppLauncherPlugin * pALP)
{
    FmIcon * fm_icon;
    GdkPixbuf * pixbuf;
    GtkWidget * icon_view;
    GtkWidget * scrolled_window;
    GtkWidget * win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget * vbox;
    GtkTreeModel * tree_model;
    //GtkWidget * fileBtn;
    //GtkWidget * picBtn;
    //GtkWidget * musicBtn;
    GtkWidget * button;
    GtkWidget * image;
    GtkWidget * label;
    GtkWidget * hbox;
    GtkWidget * innerVbox;
    GtkWidget * alignment;

    gtk_window_maximize(GTK_WINDOW(win));
    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    alignment = gtk_alignment_new(0.5, 0.5, 0,0);
    /*picBtn = gtk_button_new();
    musicBtn = gtk_button_new();
    vidBtn = gtk_button_new();*/

    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(win), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_skip_taskbar_hint(GTK_WINDOW(win), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_skip_pager_hint(GTK_WINDOW(win), TRUE);

    hbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 0);

    button = gtk_button_new();
    innerVbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button),innerVbox);
    fm_icon = fm_icon_from_name("sr-applauncher-files");
    pixbuf = fm_pixbuf_from_icon(fm_icon, pALP->app_icon_size);
    if (fm_icon)
        g_object_unref(fm_icon);
    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);
    if (pixbuf)
        g_object_unref(pixbuf);
    label = gtk_label_new("Files");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(innerVbox), image, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(innerVbox), label, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(button), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(files_folder),pALP);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button, FALSE,FALSE,0);


    button = gtk_button_new();
    innerVbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button),innerVbox);
    fm_icon = fm_icon_from_name("sr-applauncher-music");
    pixbuf = fm_pixbuf_from_icon(fm_icon, pALP->app_icon_size);
    if (fm_icon)
        g_object_unref(fm_icon);
    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);
    if (pixbuf)
        g_object_unref(pixbuf);
    label = gtk_label_new("Music");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(innerVbox), image, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(innerVbox), label, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(button), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(music_folder), pALP);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button, FALSE,FALSE,0);

    button = gtk_button_new();
    innerVbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button),innerVbox);
    fm_icon = fm_icon_from_name("sr-applauncher-pictures");
    pixbuf = fm_pixbuf_from_icon(fm_icon, pALP->app_icon_size);
    if (fm_icon)
        g_object_unref(fm_icon);
    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);
    if (pixbuf)
        g_object_unref(pixbuf);
    label = gtk_label_new("Pictures");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(innerVbox), image, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(innerVbox), label, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(button), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(pictures_folder), pALP);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button, FALSE,FALSE,0);


    button = gtk_button_new();
    innerVbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button),innerVbox);
    fm_icon = fm_icon_from_name("sr-applauncher-videos");
    pixbuf = fm_pixbuf_from_icon(fm_icon, pALP->app_icon_size);
    if (fm_icon)
        g_object_unref(fm_icon);
    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);
    if (pixbuf)
        g_object_unref(pixbuf);
    label = gtk_label_new("Videos");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(innerVbox), image, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(innerVbox), label, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(button), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(videos_folder), pALP);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button, FALSE,FALSE,0);


    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), alignment, FALSE,FALSE,0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(alignment), hbox);


    scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), scrolled_window, TRUE,TRUE,0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), vbox);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_shadow_type(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolled_window), GTK_SHADOW_IN);

    icon_view = gtk_icon_view_new_with_model(create_and_fill_model(pALP));
    g_object_unref(pALP->list_store);       /* destroy model automatically with view */
    gtk_icon_view_set_selection_mode(GTK_ICON_VIEW(icon_view), GTK_SELECTION_SINGLE);
    gtk_icon_view_set_reorderable(GTK_ICON_VIEW(icon_view), TRUE);
    gtk_icon_view_set_text_column(GTK_ICON_VIEW(icon_view), COL_DISPLAY_NAME);
    gtk_icon_view_set_pixbuf_column(GTK_ICON_VIEW(icon_view), COL_PIXBUF);
    gtk_icon_view_set_tooltip_column(GTK_ICON_VIEW(icon_view), COL_TOOLTIP);
    //g_signal_connect(icon_view, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(icon_view_onButtonPressed), pALP);

    tree_model = gtk_icon_view_get_model(GTK_ICON_VIEW(icon_view));
    g_signal_connect(icon_view, "item-activated", G_CALLBACK(icon_view_onItemActivated), pALP);

    g_signal_connect(win, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(appluncher_store_state), pALP);

    //gtk_tree_model_foreach(GTK_TREE_MODEL(pALP->list_store), foreach_func, pALP);

    //_menu_cache_lookup_sync("appLuncher.menu");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), icon_view);

    gtk_widget_show_all(scrolled_window);

    pALP->applauncher_window = win;

}
```

I am currently thinking of setting transient and `gtk_widgets_set_even(widget, GDK_MASK_FOCUS_CHANGEd)`.

#### Is there any other way as this will assumably work on popups but my window doesn't contain pop ups.

Comment: Have you come up with any solution?

Comment: I believe your change mask combined with the signal handler for "focus-out-event" should do the trick.

Comment: No solution yet, my window doesn't accept focus and never will as it is maximized, to the point only the lxde panel is visible. meaning, when clicking on lxpanel it will close. That's the catch, need to check whether the user clicked out of the window, without focus. X,Y coordinates or try passing LXpanel as parameter, but doing so results in segmentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that using another library to get general mouse information, would work best, for example curses something like this:

```
#include<curses.h>
GSList* List; //This is a singly linked list provided by glib as well.
g_timeout_add_seconds(1, callback, List);
void callback(void* pointer){
    MEVENT event;
    ch = getch();
    if(ch == KEY_MOUSE){
        if(getmouse(&event) == OK){
            /* Do some thing with the event */
       }
    }
}
```

use the list to store any widgets that you will be altering